# See multiple ways to obtain ILogger in Azure Functions 6 from docs and templates, what are the differences?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, .net-6.0, azure-functions-runtime

I'm using Azure Functions 6 (.NET 6, isolated), with Application Insights enabled.

From different versions of Visual Studio, Azure Functions Core Tools, the default Microsoft templates and other docs showed a variety of ways to obtain `ILogger`. I've seen:

1. Constructor injection of `ILoggerFactory` (from a default MS template):

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public MyFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyFunction>();
}
```

2. Getting it from the `FunctionContext` (also from default MS template):

```
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(...)] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("MyFunction);
}
```

3. Injecting `ILogger` directly into the `Run` method:

```
public static void Run(EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ICollector<string> outputSbMsg, ILogger logger)
```

4. Regular ASP.NET Core constructor injection of `ILogger<T>`:

```
private readonly ILogger<MyFunction> _logger;

public MyFunction(ILogger<MyFunction> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

What are the differences of all these methods and which ones are the best to use?

Comment: Number 4 is the preferred way. Number 1 isnt good because you are injecting a service you don’t really want – you want a logger not a logger factory. Number 2 should only be used if you want to specify the logger name. Number 3 doesn’t specify a logger name and depending on the DI container you use may not auto fill the logger name from the injecting type. Having log entries from a logger without name would make it hard to associate which part of your app issued the log entries. Therefore you should use 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 4.  Regular ASP.NET Core constructor injection of  `ILogger<T>`:

```cs
private readonly ILogger<MyFunction> _logger;
public MyFunction(ILogger<MyFunction> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

- It is the most preferable way to use **Logger** in your project.
- Using a **logger** in your project depends on your need.
- In the above way, you can use where ever you want to use the logger in your code.
- If you are using a ***smaller function project*** you can use whatever methods you want. But when it comes to ***Large function Projects*** obviously we were using **multiple classes** so everywhere creating a ***logger*** is more complicated. So using this constructor we can use where ever we want just calling the constructor to log your telemetry.

#### 3.  Injecting  `ILogger`  directly into the  `Run`  method:

```cs
public static void Run(EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ICollector<string> outputSbMsg, ILogger logger)
```

In this way, we can access the **logger** inside the **specific Run** method. outer **Run** it is not able to access.

#### 2.  Getting it from the  `FunctionContext`  (also from default MS template):

```cs
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(...)] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("MyFunction);
}
```

Which is similar to the 3rd point. But the difference between 2nd and 3rd was using ***Execution context***. The Execution context contains the ***function information*** so we can get the details of the functions in an Execution context.

#### 1.  Constructor injection of  `ILoggerFactory`  (from a default MS template):

```cs
private readonly ILogger _logger;
public MyFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyFunction>();
}
```

Here `ILoggerFactory` is brings together all the collections of `ILoggerProvider`s, and the `ILoggerFactory` creates `ILogger<T>` instances for the application. It contains `ILogger`, `ILogger<T>`, `ILoggerProvider` and `ILoggerFactory`. so using this we can use the all usages of **ILogger**.

Either you can use the **1st** or **4th** approach which is the effective way to use **ILogging**.